# Let $\varphi $:$G\to H$ be an onto group homomorphism. Show that if $K \unlhd G$, then $\varphi(K)\unlhd H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\varphi$: $G\to H$ be an onto group homomorphism. Show that if $K \unlhd G$, then $\varphi(K)\unlhd H$.

This problem was in my abstract book, but does not explain why it is true.  It is provided as an example and I was wondering if someone could help by providing the subsequent proof of this statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\varphi(K)$ is normal in $H$ if and only if $h\varphi(K)h^{-1}=\varphi(K)$ for all $h\in H$.  Note that $\varphi(g)\varphi(K)\varphi(g)^{-1} = \varphi(gKg^{-1})=\varphi(K)$ for all $g\in G$.  So how can you use the remaining assumptions to "pull" the $h$ inside of $\varphi$?

Comment: Because it is onto, then we know that h and $h^{-1}$ is used somewhere in g. Is this the last connection to make?

Comment: Yes.  For any $h\in H$ there exists $g\in G$ with $\varphi(g)=h$.  Note that it then follows that $\varphi(g^{-1})=\varphi(g)^{-1}=h^{-1}$.